# Where can I find the reference to Ashta Shaktis of Devi Durga?

Tags: durga, shaktism, reference-request

There are eight Shaktis of Devi Durga who are worshipped during the Ashtami of Durgapuja. They are: Ugrachanda, Prachanda, Chandogra, Chandanayika, Atichanda, Chamunda, Chanda and Chandavati. They reside inside the Sarvatobhadramandala, which is drawn during the Durga Puja Ritual. To be specific, they reside at the base of the 8 petals that come out of the central circle of the mandala. They are not part of 64 yoginis, as 64 yoginis are also invoked at the middle of the petal separately. Their names and their ritual worship methods are mentioned in every Durga Puja manual (Puja Paddhati Books). However, unfortunately, they do not provide any scriptural source.

Now, my question is where can I find the reference to Ashta Shaktis? Durga Puja is performed according to Kalika Puran or Devi Puran (this is different from Srimad Devi Bhagavatam; it is a short upapurana that mainly contains instructions for different pujas) or Nandikeshwar Puran. Now, Nandikeshwar Puran is lost. So, I guess, it could be found somewhere inside Kalika Puran or Devi Puran. Or it could be found in any of the 64 Sakta Tantras. I am not sure. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little surprised that they don't appear in any of the texts you mentioned, which would make sense. However, all eight are mentioned in the Garuda Purana- but not all together.

Seven of the eight are mentioned in the [Brihaspata Samhita 133](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122613.html). Six are included in the list, but a few sentences later, Chandanayika is also mentioned:

> Brahma said:—The ninth day of the moon’s increase, marked by the asterism Uttarashada, is called Mahanavami. A gift or a ceremonial ablution made under the auspices of this astral combination bears immortal fruits. The Goddess Durga worshipped on that day grants infinite piety to her votary...The Goddess should be contemplated as respectively holding a human skull, a dagger, a bell, a mirror, a Tarjani, a bow, a banner, a small drum, and a noose in her left hands, and a spear, a club, a trident, a thunderbolt, a sword, a mace, an arrow, a discus and a rod in her right. The goddess should be worshipped fully equipped as described before. The different manifestations of the Goddess, such as, **Ugrachanda, Prachanda, Chandogra, Chandavati, Chandarupa and Atichandika** should be as well worshipped on the occasion. Of these Ugrachanda is coloured like yellow pigment. Prachanda is coloured like rosy dawn; Chandogra is sable; **Chanda-nayika** is blue; Chandarupi, yellow; and Atichandika, grey. Each of these divinities should be contemplated as standing sidewise on a lion, with her left leg elevated and thurst out.

(Note that the name is given as Atichandika, not simply Atichanda)

Chanda, for some reason, is included elsewhere in the text, in the [Agastya Samhita 24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122499.html):

> Suta said:—I will now describe the most excellent adoration of Ganas[2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122499.html) which gives all and even heaven. The worshipper should adore the seats of Ganas, the images of Ganas and the lord of Ganas. Heart and other limbs should be assigned to Durga. The sandals of the preceptor, the seat of Durga and her image should be adored with the mantram:—“Hrim, O Durga, protect.” Then assignment should be made to the eight Saktis, called Chandikas, viz **Rudrachanda, Prachanda, Chandogra, Chandanayika, Chanda, Chandavati and Chandarupa** with the mantram “O Durga, O Durga, O protectress” Then Vajra, Khanga and other Mudras of Shiva should be adored in the south-east. Then Sadasiva, the lord of goblins and the lotus seat [should be adored.]

I'm not sure why, but Rudrachanda replaces Ugrachanda, and Atichanda is missing in this part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the references of Aṣṭa śaktis in kālikā puraṇa. Though they are not mentioned as śaktis. They are mentioned as eight auspicious yoginīs. Apart from that 64 yoginīs are also mentioned separately. Here are the relevant verses -

> ugracaṇḍādikaḥ pūjyā-stathāṣṭau yoginīḥ śubhāḥ || kālikā purāṇa 60.52

> Worship Ugracaṇḍa etc. eight auspicious yoginīs (translation from Bengali done by me).

Their names are mentioned later -

> ugracaṇḍā pracaṇḍā ca caṇḍogrā caṇḍanāyikā
> caṇḍā caṇḍavatī caiba caṇḍarūpāticaṇḍikā
> etaḥ sampūjayenmadhye maṇḍalasya biśeṣataḥ || kālikā purāṇa 63.120

> Worship ugracaṇḍā, pracaṇḍā, caṇḍogrā, caṇḍanāyikā, caṇḍā, caṇḍavatī, caṇḍarūpā and caṇḍikā in special ways inside the maṇḍala. (I did the translation from Bengali)